# Confused about the import syntax in django for Render()

Tags: python, django

Im trying to understand the period in `from django.shortcuts import render`

Does it mean from the django directory in the shortcuts file?

Or does it mean from the django directory, from the shortcuts directory, import the render file?

Comment: `import django.shortcuts;print(djang.shortcuts)` should show where it came from.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it means from the `django` package in the `shortcuts` module import the `render` function.  However that isn't a definition that applies to all import statements of the same structure.

A package is roughly speaking a directory containing 1 or more modules.

A module in python is roughly any `.py` file.

So your first guess was right, however it isn't consistent.  For example one common `django` import statement is:

`from django.views import View`

but you won't find a `View` module inside the `django.views` directory.

`View` is actually a class that is defined in the `django.views.generic.base` module.

Comment: yes you are right i found that file under Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py

Comment: @jarjarbinks99  Great, now check out my second example and you will see that it isn't always so simple.

Comment: ah yes I hear you. I see the function in the base file. I get where I should be looking though for all of them. I appreciate your response man